# How to make a BitArray readonly?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

How do I make a `System.Collection.BitArray` readonly? I looked for the follwing but without any success yet...

- `myBitArray.IsReadOnly = true;` does not work as the property has only a getter.
- `myBitArray.SetReadOnly()` does not work as there is no such method.
- `new BitArray(myBitArray, readonly: true)` does not work as there is no such constructor overload.
- `myBitArray.Clone(readonly: true)` does not work as there is no such method overload.
- `myBitArray.AsReadOnly()` does not work as there is no such extension method.
- And neither is there a `BitArrayBuilder`...

What am I missing?

(Am using .NET 4.8 to 6.0, multi-targeting)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray.isreadonly?view=net-6.0 says "this property is always false". It is required because `BitArray` implements `IList`.

Comment: This isn't a solution to your problem, but maybe will keep you from continuing down a rabbit hole. It seems as though that property will always return false and it was only included to satisfy the IList interface. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray.isreadonly?view=net-6.0#system-collections-bitarray-isreadonly

Comment: As those docs say _”**A collection that is read-only is simply a collection with a wrapper that prevents modifying the collection**; therefore, if changes are made to the underlying collection, the read-only collection reflects those changes.”_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation of BitArray.IsReadOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray.isreadonly?view=net-6.0)

> This property is always false.
>
> BitArray implements the IsReadOnly property because it is required by the System.Collections.IList interface.

That explanation seem a bit odd to me, since BitArray does not seem to implement `IList`, only `ICollection`. But that is the explanation given.

If you are in some particular need for a read only bitArray an option might be to create your own class or a wrapper.

Comment: Interesting observation, you are right. That member does not implement an interface.

Comment: That I didn't expect, that there is no support at all by the framework! But it explains why I did not find anything...